# Android: How to display an image in its original size

Tags: android, image, scale, image-size

I create an bitmap image from byte array and display it in an ImageView. The `android:layout_width` and `android:layout_height` of the ImageView are set to wrap_content, and the `android:scaleType` is set to center. But the image is still scaled to the screen size.

Is there a way to display the image at its original size (just like using the android:src attribute directly)?

CODE:

create bitmap from byte array:

```
private Bitmap decodeBitmap(byte[] data) {
    return BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);
}
```

and layout of the ImageView:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/logo"
    android:scaleType="centerInside"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

set image to ImageView:

```
mView.setImageBitmap(mBitmap);
```

Comment: Please add the code you are using..

Answer (score 1):

Please use this code
if the stream is from resource

```
InputStream is = this.getResources().openRawResource(imageId1); 
Bitmap originalBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
ImageView myimage.setImageBitmap(originalBitmap); 
myimage.setScaleType(ScaleType.MATRIX);
```

Comment: The image still scaled to fit the screen size. I use setImageBitmap() here to set the image to ImageView.

Comment: The image is created from byte array by using the decodeBitmap()

Comment: why u r using decode stream use like this originalBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);

Comment: ok, InputStream is = this.getResources().openRawResource(imageId1);
          originalBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);myimage.setImageBitmap(originalBitmap);
          myimage.setScaleType(ScaleType.MATRIX);

Comment: Does it matter where the image from? The stream is not from resource.

Comment: ok, sorry, i don't know other things, means if it is not from resource . if it is from resource i will be useful.