# How to keep the original image size as it is when it set to image view

Tags: android, android-layout

I am setting one PNG image to ImageView. when i had checked its width & height from outside(Photoshop)it is 42 X 42 but when I set it to ImageView its width & height get reduced automatically.I had set its layout params as `Wrap_Content` but still its size reduces so what could be the problem?

I have already tried from the link [Android: How to display an image in its original size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7873146/android-how-to-display-an-image-in-its-original-size) but it is giving me the same result.

Comment: can you show your xml?

Comment: place your png in res/drawable-nodpi

Comment: did you try with android:scaleType="fitxy"?